# joomla jce flash button is missing

Tags: php, joomla

I have installed the jce 1.5 and mediabox to enable the admin to insert the flash videos by uploading the swf files or by browsing the url from the youtube

I have enabled the mediabox plugin

but I don't know where is the flash button is suppose to appear in JCE.

please help

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching on the net

I found **SWFContent Pro & SWFContent Pro Module**

this solved my problem :)